# Integrating Microsoft team into my web app

Tags: microsoft-teams

I have a web app where if a user signs up, a notification is sent to the slack channel. I want to achieve the same thing in Microsoft team but I cant find any good resources. When a new user signs up, a message will be posted into the microsoft team group.Will it be possible to do this?

Comment: The simplest solution would be to use the [Custom Bot](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/microsoft-teams/custombot) feature within Teams, but note that it is a one-off solution.

Answer (score 2):

This can be easily achieved in Microsoft Teams using [Connectors](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/microsoft-teams/connectors).
Here are the steps to post data to any channel:

1. In Microsoft Teams, choose the More options (⋯) button next to the
   channel name in the list of channels and then choose Connectors.
2. Add an **Incoming webhook** and copy the webhook URL.
3. You can post [Message Card](https://messagecardplayground.azurewebsites.net/) given below to this URL using
   Postman/Fiddler/Code.

   ```
   {
           "summary": "Alert!",
           "themeColor": "0078D7",
           "sections": [
           {    
                "activityTitle": "Web app event",
                "text": "Something happened in the web app!"
           }],
           "potentialAction": [
           {
                   "@type": "OpenUri",
                   "name": "View event",
                   "targets": [
                           { "os": "default", "uri": "http://mywebapp.com/path/to/event" }]
           }]
   }
   ```

You can also Build your own Connector with custom configurations.

Comment: Be sure to set the Content-type HTTP header to "application/JSON".